# SetInterval cancelled because of page change

Tags: javascript, button, click, setinterval

I want to make a script to click on a button with a specific ID every 1s, on the page I want.

So I use setInterval, and I have this :

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("NextButton").click();
}, 1000);
```

So, when I run my script using Chrome Developer Tools, the button is clicked once, but then the script stops.

I think it's because the button clicked make the page to change (like a submit button on a survey).

So I seek for a solution to keep the script running, even if another page of the survey-like is loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: You might have to embed the script in a separate iFrame, from what I gather from your question.

Comment: But to embed it, I have to own the page, however, I want this to be independant from the website visited.

Comment: If the button submits a form and takes the user to a new page, then effectively the script will stop executing because the user will be on a new page. In any case, I think we need more information to be able to figure out this issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. Is there any method to restart the script automatically when the script is stopped ?

Comment: A hack is to submit the timer along with the page and set it in a hidden tag and use that to initiate timer on next page.